# Does R has method like fillna(method = "ffill") in python?

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am learning using R to do data cleaning work. Just encounter a question that I could deal with by python but not in R.

The dataset is like this.[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtKWq.png)

I want to concat the first two columns and assign it as index. The first thing I need to do is to fillna('ffill') the first column. Then I need concat two columns.

Could you tell me how to do this in R (tidyverse is better)?

The result should like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sASdh.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read the guidance at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and note in particular that input data should NOT be given in images since no one other than you can then easily use it.  Also the question needs to provide a clear explanation of what is wanted without reference to Python by  providing an explanation in words and giving a reproducible example showing input, expected output and also the code for what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these.  Be sure to read the help pages since many of them have arguments which may need to be set depending on what you want.

```
zoo::na.locf  (last observation carried forward)
zoo::na.locf0
tidyr::fill
data.table::nafill
```

zoo also has `na.aggregate`, `na.approx`, `na.contiguous`, `na.fill`, `na.spline`, `na.StructTS` and `na.trim` for other forms of NA filling and tidyr also has `replace_na`.